# How can I append directories to $PATH in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, build, path, directory, eclipse-cdt

This C project I'm working on has a script which is run as part of the build, which requires some folder to be in the $PATH. But - other projects shouldn't have it in their path, nor should Eclipse itself. So, this is not about *replacing* the path but *appending* to it for a specific project.

I couldn't find a way to do this in Eclipse's project settings dialog; does this feature exist? If not, can you suggest a workaround other than having my script itself append to $PATH?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To edit the path the build is run with, in the `Project Properties` choose `C/C++ Build` | `Environment` and add your new Path entry by pressing `Add...` and filling in `PATH` for `Name` and `/your/path` for `VALUE`. Note that CDT assumes that if the variable (`PATH` in this case) is already defined that you want to append to it. (You probably want to check the `Add to all configurations` check too.)

Here is a screenshot:

[image: buildenv]

### This is how to do the same for launch configurations

In the `Environment` tab for the specific launch configuration you want to edit the `PATH`, set the `PATH` to be `/tmp/abcd:${env_var:PATH}`

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Running the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Updated PATH with /tmp/abcd prepended");
    puts(getenv("PATH"));
    puts("Saved version of PATH in case we need that");
    puts(getenv("ORIGPATH"));
    return 0;
}
```

And you should observe this output:

```
Updated PATH with /tmp/abcd prepended
/tmp/abcd:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
Saved version of PATH in case we need that
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: I have just realized I have not answered your question because I did a run configuration, not a build one.

Comment: OK, I have tried to answer the question, but I failed to delete the original part of my answer (i.e. I couldn't bring myself to delete it - trying to justify it that maybe it will be useful to someone else down the road)

Comment: Very, very good answer.  I realized that I was trying to use both PATH and HOME together.  After applying to PATH, it took me a while to realize that the same thing needs to be applied to HOME.  $PATH and $HOME, by themselves, don't work.